# $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5$. $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ are natural numbers. Find maximum of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, permutations, number-systems

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5$.

$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ are natural numbers.

Find maximum of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$.

Answer (score 8):

**Claim.** Assume $x_1,\ldots,x_5\in\Bbb N$ with $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5$.
Then up to permutation we have $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(1,1,1,2,5)$ or $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(1,1,1,3,3)$.
In particular, all $x_i$ are $\le 5$.

*Proof.*
We may assume wlog. that $x_1\le\ldots\le x_5$.
Then $x_1+\ldots+x_5\le 5x_5$ and we conclude $x_1x_2x_3x_4\le 5$. This leaves us only with the following possibilities for $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$:
$$(1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,2), (1,1,1,3), (1,1,1,4), (1,1,1,5), (1,1,2,2).$$
These lead to the following conditions on $x_5$:
$$\begin{align} 4+x_5=x_5&\implies\text{impossible}\\
5+x_5=2x_5&\implies x_5=5\\
6+x_5=3x_5&\implies x_5=3\\
7+x_5=4x_5&\implies \text{impossible}\\
8+x_5=5x_5&\implies \text{impossible}\\
6+x_5=4x_5&\implies x_5=2\\
\end{align}$$
$\square$

Comment: Actually $6+4x_5=x_5$ admits a solution  $x_5=2$.  But yes, $5$ is the maximum.